# DataTable Row Group doesn't work with filters column and column sorting

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using p-table with Row Group there is the link for primeNG doc https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/rowgroup

Adding filters and column sort breaks the row grouping.
See a sample project for repro.
Try to filter by year "1990" you will get 2 rows as a result but the brand group is lost.
Sorting makes compete mass by putting rows on the top without any group

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablerowgroup-demo-vp1wjb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

**The one way to fix it somehow find what rows are visible in the table and call the updateRowGroupMetaData() with these rows, so how do I know what rows are visible especially after filter??
Maybe there is another way to fix it?**

Template:

```
<p-table #tt [columns]="cols" [value]="cars" sortField="brand" sortMode="single" (onSort)="onSort()">
<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field">
                {{col.header}}
                <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field" ariaLabel="Activate to sort"
                        ariaLabelDesc="Activate to sort in descending order"
                        ariaLabelAsc="Activate to sort in ascending order">
                    </p-sortIcon>
            </th>
        </tr>
         <tr>
                <th *ngFor="let col of columns" >
                    <input pInputText type="text" (input)="tt.filter($event.target.value, col.field, 'contains')"
                        [value]="tt.filters[col.field] ? tt.filters[col.field].value : ''" style="width:100%">
                </th>
            </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
        <tr class="ui-widget-header" *ngIf="rowGroupMetadata[rowData.brand].index === rowIndex">
            <td colspan="3">
                <span style="font-weight:bold">{{rowData.brand}}</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{rowData.vin}}</td>
            <td>{{rowData.year}}</td>
            <td>{{rowData.color}}</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

component:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.carService.getCarsMedium().then(cars => {
      this.cars = cars;
      this.updateRowGroupMetaData();
    });
     this.cols = [
      { field: "vin", header: "vin" },
      { field: "year", header: "year" },
      { field: "color", header: "color" },
    
    ];
  }

  onSort() {
    this.updateRowGroupMetaData();
  }

  updateRowGroupMetaData() {
    this.rowGroupMetadata = {};
    if (this.cars) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.cars.length; i++) {
        let rowData = this.cars[i];
        let brand = rowData.brand;
        if (i == 0) {
          this.rowGroupMetadata[brand] = { index: 0, size: 1 };
        } else {
          let previousRowData = this.cars[i - 1];
          let previousRowGroup = previousRowData.brand;
          if (brand === previousRowGroup) this.rowGroupMetadata[brand].size++;
          else this.rowGroupMetadata[brand] = { index: i, size: 1 };
        }
      }
    }
  }
```